# FOREIGN KEY ..again

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have read and searched all the site, but nothing I had found worked for me...so please help a newbie understand what he is doing wrong.

So I am trying to create an add to favorite function.
 I need to create 3 tables. The first two worked like magic, but the 3rd one ...well I got in the trouble with the  FOREIGN KEY

I get no error message, but it won't create the 3rd table.

Here are my codes:

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","");

$db = mysql_select_db("mydb");



mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users

(
userid bigint,
firstname varchar(25),
lastname varchar(15),
email varchar(250),
gender varchar(10),
username varchar(15),
password varchar(15),
age int,
activ boolean,
date TIMESTAMP NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)ENGINE=INNODB

");


mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products ( 
  productid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  productname varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
  productdescription varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
  price decimal(6,2) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`productid`) 
) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 "); 


mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favorites
(
  userid bigint NOT NULL,
  productid int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid, productid),
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES user (userid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (productid) REFERENCES product (productid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB
");
echo "The DataBase was successfully created!";
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: where you facing error. Please attach your error message.

Comment: advise for a newbie - don't learn how to do the query using mysql() - this has been deprecated and is not as secure as using PDO - try to learn that and save yourself the headache later trying to convert your thinking.

Comment: Sorry, I get no error message, but it won't create the 3rd table.

Comment: Then how do you know that the error is related to foreign keys?

Comment: Please run your third table query directly to mysql and in that it shows error message from that you can get better idea.

Comment: Check for sql errors in your code by inspecting the return values of the mysql_query() calls and printing out mysql_error(). Or you could simply run the 3 create table statements in your favourite sql manager application.

Comment: errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"userid" of "user" table must be primary key.

Answer (score 1):

The foreign keys refer to non-existing tables.

The tables are names `users` and `products` while the third table refers to them as `user` and `product` (singular).

Comment: Indeed to problem was the userid within the users it wasn't the primary key. Thank you very much for the help!